# GeoLocation React Native

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

I am trying to get the user location my code is working fine in the 
ios and in the android it does not throw the error when user denies 
the location permission.

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
      this.geoFailure, geoOptions);
        this.refresh();
      }

geoSuccess = (position) => { //Success callback when user allow the 
                              location
    this.setState({
        ready:true,
        where: {lat: 
  position.coords.latitude,lng:position.coords.longitude }
    })
}


geoFailure = (err) => {  // i am not getting any error when user 
                            denies the location permission in the 
                            case of android.
    this.setState({error: err.message});
    console.log("Errror",err)
    console.log(err.message)
    if(err.message='User denied access to location services'&&Platform.OS==='ios'){
        this.props.screenName==='SPLASH'&&!this.state.ready?NavigatorService.navigate(LOCATION_PERMISSION):null;
    } 
}


refresh=()=>   // Refreshing the list when the AppState becomes 
                  active 
    let geoOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 30000,
        maximumAge: 60 * 60 * 24
    };
    this.setState({ready:false, error: null });
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( this.geoSuccess, this.geoFailure, geoOptions);
}
```

I am able to navigate the user to another screen in the case of ios 
if it doesn't provide the location permissions but in the case of 
the android it does not giving any error when user does not provide 
the location.

I am not getting how to do it , i am new to the react native.

I am not getting, what i am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you take permission in android ?If yes,then what is code of permisssion in android?

Comment: yes i have taken the permission, its in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Android api 23 and onwards,you must take permisssion runtime not only manifest

Comment: yes i have done that

Answer (score 0):

use PermissionsAndroid

```
import {
   PermissionsAndroid
} from 'react-native';

 const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position) => {
            addLocation(position.coords);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.error(error);
          },
          { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 },
        );
      } else {
        console.log('location permission denied');
      }
```

Comment: make a repo and share link

Comment: whats the issue please share